# Is it possible to use Vuforia Engine SDK for native to recognize images from Cloud Recognition?

Tags: android, ios, cloud, vuforia

Within the [sample apps](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples), it doesn't appear that the native iOS/Android sample apps can recognize images or samples from the Cloud Recognition API.

The only sample app that shows that feature is Unity, which leads me to a few questions:

1. Will Vuforia Engine SDK (10.14+) recognize images from the Cloud Recognition API?
2. If so, can those images then be tracked/used in AR?
3. If NOT, can the unity SDK be leveraged in iOS/Android using swift/java bindings? Or how are people using the Cloud Recognition APIs in their apps? Any sample apps would be HUGELY helpful.

Building core sample apps for iOS/Android
Read the download sample app features
Scoured SO/forums to try and get a better understanding of the functionality

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the current native Vuforia Engine samples do not demonstrate the Cloud Recognition feature. However, the features demonstrated in the Unity samples are also supported by our native APIs.

Thus, images can be recognized in the cloud and tracked in AR. Please see the recently reworked Vuforia Engine API reference documentation for more information on [Cloud Reco APIs](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/native/group__CloudImageTargetObserverGroup.html).

Unfortunately, the native Cloud Reco samples were deprecated with the release of Vuforia Engine 10.X.